# Apply variable marker position to matlab plots

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot, subplot

I have a problem in matlab. I want to plot a graph having 5 plots. Let me go through them.
x axis for each data is from 1:500.

For plot 1 to 3, I want to place marker after every 10 values, whereas for plot 4 to 5 I want to place markers after every 5 values. Is it possible to do it ?

I followed a code something like this:

```
figure,
set(gcf, 'Position', get(0,'Screensize')); % Maximize figure.
set(gcf,'Color','white');
plot(ObjVal1(1:10:end),'*r','LineWidth',3);
hold on;
plot(ObjVal2(1:10:end),'-.b','LineWidth',3);
plot(ObjVal3(1:10:end),'+-k','LineWidth',3);
plot(ObjVal4(1:5:end),'sm','LineWidth',3);
plot(ObjVal5(1:5:end),'.b','LineWidth',3);
hold off;
title({'Fitness Value'},'FontWeight','bold','FontSize', 12,'Color','black');
xlabel('Fitness Value --->','FontWeight','bold','FontSize', 12,'Color','black');
ylabel('Iterations --->','FontWeight','bold','FontSize', 12,'Color','black');
legend('CV GDS','CV Momentum','CV Exct LS','CV Back Track','CV Conjugate GDS');
```

Then I get an output like this :

[image]

The problem is quite evident from the picture. The plots of 1-3 is given for 50 values as the subplot is taken for each 10 iterations whereas the 4th and 5th plot is given for 100 values as the subplot is taken for each 5 iterations. I do not want to do this. Basically I want the plot of all the values but with the markers placed at each 10 iterations for plot 1-3 and at each 5 iterations for plots 4-5.

Thanks everybody in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use first argument to [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) to specify x-axis positions of the markers:

```
plot(1:10:numel(ObjVal3), ObjVal3(1:10:end),'+-k', 'LineWidth', 3);
plot(1:5:numel(ObjVal4), ObjVal4(1:5:end), 'sm', 'LineWidth', 3)
```

Comment: Thank you lots. It really works. But can you please explain the code snippet to me!

Comment: The only thing I've changed with respect to your code is that I've included a first argument to `plot` (`1:10:numel(ObjVal3)` in the first case). That argument specifies the x-axis position of the markers (in this case: 1, 11, 21,...). In your original code you didn' t specify that argument, which causes Matlab to always use 1, 2, 3... as x-axis positions

Comment: Thanks for the lucid explanation